# SQL: Is it possible to add a dummy column in a select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to add a dummy column to a simple select statement in certain circumstances:

`Select Id, EndOfcol default '~' from Main where id > 40`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, it's actually a constant value.

```
SELECT id, '~' AS EndOfcol
FROM Main
WHERE id > 40
```

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes you may want to cast the datatype of the constant especially if you plan to add other data to it later:

```
SELECT id, cast('~' as varchar(20)) AS EndOfcol FROM Main WHERE id > 40
```

This is especially useful if you want to add a NULL column and then later figure out the information that goes into it as NULL will be cast as int automatically.

```
SELECT id,  cast(NULL as varchar(20))  AS Myfield FROM Main WHERE id > 40
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible it can be constant or can be conditional

```
SELECT id, '~' EndOfcol FROM Main WHERE id > 40
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution is to add a column like this:

```
Select Id, EndOfcol default '~', space(2) as Dummy from Main where id > 40
```